# bluetooth module and pic

Tags: hc-05

I am currently working on a project that requires bluetooth module and pic. I need to get the ID or address of the connected device.Any idea how can i do it. I only know that this is done using AT commands.

Comment: Which bluetooth module are you using? Can you show us the sketch you used to try and get the address?

Comment: i am using HC-05 module.I am connecting this module with my phone and want to access my phone's ID or address.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the sketch you are using.